# ¿Cómo evitar que la imagen guarde volteada?

Tags: php, jquery, imagen, dropzone.js

Cuando recargo la imagen, ésta se ve invertida pero solo con algunas, y todas se cargaron con el `DROZONE.JS` , tengo un formulario que sirve solo para cargar la imagen arrastrando, solo se permite subir una foto ya que se usa para la foto de perfil de cada niño cumpleañero, luego la foto se carga y el programa se dirige al controlador que valida los campos y luego crea una carpeta con la identificación del usuario si no existe y finalmente guarda la imagen utilizando la identificación del usuario como el nombre y así reemplazar la foto anterior, pero con ciertas fotos se da la vuelta y la razón no, y en la base de datos se almacenan el nombre de la foto y su extensión.

El formulario que muestra la foto está cargado por otro controlador que carga la foto y la información del usuario, y luego, mediante una consulta, la vista se llena con la información obtenida.

En este momento, ya inserta la imagen y almacena el nombre en la base de datos, pero cuando la carga, la ve con un giro de 90 grados.

```
 <!--View-->


 <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "pruebas", "xxxx");
    mysqli_select_db($link, "colitali_iqpantallas");
    $tildes = $link->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //Para que se muestren las tildes correctamente
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM birthdays ORDER BY id");
    $estado ="active";
    $contador=0;
    $delete="";
?>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <table id="tableBirthdays" class="table display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
                <th scope="col">Cargo</th>
                <th scope="col">Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                <th scope="col">Inicio del cargo</th>
                <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Cargo</th>
                <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                <th>Inicio del cargo</th>
                <th>Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody class="contentTable">


<?php
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $estado="";
        $col_name=$fila['name'];
        $col_surname=$fila['surname'];
        $col_job=$fila['job'];
        $col_id=$fila['id']; 
        $col_start=$fila['start'];
        $col_cumple=$fila['day']."/".$fila['month']."/".$fila['year'];
        $col_image=($fila['image']==NULL) ? "default.png" : $col_id."/".$fila['image'] ;
        $delete .= '<option class="opcionBirthdays" data-src="birthday" value="'.$col_id.'" title="'.$col_name." ".$col_surname.'">';
        $delete .= $col_id.". ";
        $delete .= $col_name." ".$col_surname;
        $delete .= '</option>';
?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label><?php echo $col_id; ?></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $col_name; ?>" width="150" id="birthdaysName-<?php echo $col_id; ?>" required/>
                            <label class="d-none"><?php echo $col_name; ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button type="button" value="Guardar" name="detail" class="botonIQ btnGuardar" data-action='controller/uploadBirthday.php?tipo=1&code=<?php echo $col_id; ?>'>Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $col_surname; ?>" width="150" id="birthdaysSurname-<?php echo $col_id; ?>" required/>
                            <label class="d-none"><?php echo $col_surname; ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button type="button" value="Guardar" name="detail" class="botonIQ btn-xs btnGuardar" data-action='controller/uploadBirthday.php?tipo=2&code=<?php echo $col_id; ?>'>Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="job" value="<?php echo $col_job; ?>" width="150" id="birthdaysJob-<?php echo $col_id; ?>"required/>
                            <label class="d-none"><?php echo $col_job; ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button type="button" value="Guardar" name="detail" class="botonIQ btnGuardar" data-action='controller/uploadBirthday.php?tipo=3&code=<?php echo $col_id; ?>'>Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input id="birthdaysBirthday-<?php echo $col_id; ?>" class="datepicker form-control" data-elemento="birthdays" width="150" value="<?php echo $col_cumple; ?>" name="birthday" readonly required/>
                            <label class="d-none"><?php echo $col_cumple; ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button type="button" value="Guardar" name="detail" class="botonIQ btn-xs btnGuardar" data-action='controller/uploadBirthday.php?tipo=4&code=<?php echo $col_id; ?>'>Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input id="birthdaysStart-<?php echo $col_id; ?>" class="datepicker form-control" data-elemento="birthdays" width="150" value="<?php echo $col_start; ?>" name="start" readonly required/>
                            <label class="d-none"><?php echo $col_start; ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button type="button" value="Guardar" name="detail" class="botonIQ btnGuardar" data-action='controller/uploadBirthday.php?tipo=5&code=<?php echo $col_id; ?>'>Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action='controller/uploadBirthday.php?tipo=6&code=<?php echo $col_id; ?>' class='dropzone' data-elemento="birthdays" enctype='multipart/form-data' id='birthdaysImage-<?php echo $col_id; ?>' style="height: 150px; width: 100px; font-size: 10px">
                        <img class='img-l miniImagen' width="40px" height="40px" src='images/<?php echo $col_image; ?>' />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
<?php
        $contador++;
    } 
?> 







<!-- Controller --> 

<?php
    include_once "con.php";
    switch ($_GET['tipo']) {
        case 1:
        //Modificar el nombre //error

        break;
        case 2:
        //Modificar el apellido

        break;
        case 3:
        //Modificar el cargo

        break;
        case 4:
        //Modificar la fecha de nacimiento

        break;
        case 5:
        //Modificar la fecha en la que empezo a trabjar

        break;
        case 6:
        //Modificar la imagen
            if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
                $id=$_GET['code'];
                if (!file_exists('../images/'.$id)) {
                    $oldmask = umask(0);
                    mkdir('../images/'.$id, 0777);
                    umask($oldmask);
                }
                if($fila['image']!=NULL) {
                    unlink('../images/'.$id."/".$id.'.png');
                }
                $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                $storeFolder = '../images/'.$id;
                if (!empty($_FILES)) {

                    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];             
                    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
                    $targetFile =  $targetPath.$id. ".png";
                    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); 
                    $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                    $sentencia = $con->prepare("UPDATE birthdays SET image = ? WHERE id = ?;");
                    $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$id.'.png', $id]);
                }
                else {
                    die("No se a subido nada");
                }

            }
            else {
                    die("No se a recibido nada");
            }
        break;
    }
    include_once "bitacora.php";
    header('Location: ../home.php?forms=birthdays');

    ?>
```

La imagen debe verse bien, es decir, como se tomó con el teléfono celular o la cámara, pero se ve volteada.

[image: Miren esta imagen, este es el aspecto visual del problema.]

aquí acabe de hacer un ejemplo miren el id 22 y creo que también el 52 
[Ejemplo](http://seadoglabs.com/iq/pru/home.php)

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva ya paso un poco de tiempo esta publicación pero por si alguien tiene igual el mismo problema esta fue la solución que encontré, use la librería de http://image.intervention.io/ y de esa libreria use el método orientate(), actualmente lo utilice en un proyecto de laravel pero no creo haya problemas con usarlo sin Framework.

```
$file = Input::file('archivo'); # Obtengo el nombre del input del formulario 
$extencion = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); # Se obtiene l aextencion 
$nombre = $usuario->id '.' . $extencion; # Guarde el archivo con el id del usuario
$path = public_path($ruta . $nombre); # la ruta de donde guardar la imagen 
$guardar_imagen = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->orientate(); # Aquí el método orientate hace el trabajo para colocar la imagen en la posición correcta
$guardar_imagen->resize(120,120, function($constraint){
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->save($path); # Aquí esta rende-rizando la imagen y guardando la imagen en la carpeta.
```